# How to print content of an enumerated list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enumeration

I have created an enumerated list `rank` from a list `total`. But I am not able to print any specific value from the list `rank`.

I have tried to print the specific value from the `rank` list by traversing it using a for loop but getting the error

```
    print(rank[i][0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```py
n=int(input())
total=[]
rank=sorted(list(enumerate(total)), key=lambda x:x[1])

for i in range(n):
    e,g,m,h=map(int, input().split())
    total.append([-(e + g + m + h)])

#print(total)

#print(rank)

for i in range(n):
    print(rank[i][0])
```

Input:

```
5
100 98 100 100
100 100 100 100
100 100 99 99
90 99 90 100
100 98 60 99
```

Expected Output:

`(-398,0)` if is `rank[0][0]` or so on.

Comment: ***"IndexError: list index out of range""***: May i see the output of `print(rank)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. The first question you should ask yourself in this situation is "What's the value of `rank`?" then try printing it and examining it. It will also help you in the future to make a [mre].

Comment: Thanks! I understood my mistake. I did tried printing rank but it was just that I was not realising the mistake that after data entry in total list, I should enumerate it. And in my approach I was enumerating the total list before any data entry in it and due to this print(rank) was not printing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move `rank` creation after you fill `total` then it works fine.

```
n = int(input())
total = []

for i in range(n):
    e, g, m, h = map(int, input().split())
    total.append([-(e + g + m + h)])

rank = sorted(list(enumerate(total)), key=lambda x: x[1])
for i in range(n):
    print(rank[i][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# print rank
for i in total:
    print(i[0])
```